# Trying to record from a USB sound card

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using a *UGreen USB External Stereo Sound Card* and would like to record the music from some old tapes.

I am not able to manage any kind of recording with it.

My Fedora recognizes it immediately as a *USB Advanced Audio Device* and gives me the following Profiles:

- Analog Stereo Input
- Digital Stereo (IEC958)-Input
- Analog Stereo Output
- Analog Stereo Duplex
- Analog Stereo-Output + Stereo (IEC958)-Input
- Digital Stereo (IEC958)-Output
- Digital Stereo-Output + Analog Stereo-Input
- Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)

It can be found:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7a14000 irq 36
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7a10000 irq 37
 2 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB Advanced Audio Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Advanced Audio Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full
```

Also apparently audacity is able to find it:

```
$ arecord --list-devices
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (CAPTURE) ****
Karte 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 0/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 2: Device [USB Advanced Audio Device], Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-Geräte: 0/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried to do a short recording using hw2:

```
[qohelet@localhost Audio]$ arecord -f cd -D hw2,1 -d 20 test.wav
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw2,1
arecord: main:830: Fehler beim Öffnen des Gerätes: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
[qohelet@localhost Audio]$ arecord -f cd -D hw2,0 -d 20 test.wav
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw2,0
arecord: main:830: Fehler beim Öffnen des Gerätes: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

(Both times the error is: Error during opening of the device: File or directory not found)

Inside audacity I don't have many choices. ALSA for the device; pulse/default for the input and that's it (except for the channels). I assume it takes the selection from the OS as I can get a pulse in audacity the moment I select a different profile from the Audio-Options. Everything else is essentially a line.

I have tried to stream it via VLC where my options are hw1,0 and hw2,0. I selected hw2,0 and get an error:

```
[00007fb6d8009890] access_alsa demux error: cannot open ALSA device "hw:2,0": Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
[00007fb6d801c590] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```

**The device or the resource is busy**

There had often been the recommendation for the beta-version of *audio-recorder*. But this doesn't give any information and it seems it's not even properly working (notice the two non-functional buttons):
[image]

I have tried to output from the old tape system's RCA connector to the headphones to see if the output is still working. The volume is weirdly low, but it works.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> and gives me the following Profiles

This means you have Pulseaudio installed.

> `arecord -f cd -D hw2,0 -d 20 test.wav`

The syntax I know is `hw:2` or `hw:2,0`.

> `access_alsa demux error: cannot open ALSA device "hw:2,0": Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt`

Note the syntax `hw:2,0`. And the device is busy because Pulseaudio is using it, so you can't access it directly through ALSA.

> What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Use `parecord` instead of `arecord` and record from the correct Pulseaudio device. Use `pavucontrol` or `pactl list short sources` to see sources.

Alternatively, stop or suspend Pulseaudio, then record from the ALSA device with the correct syntax.